# Using a 'complex' function within the apply family

Tags: r, anova, tapply

I am attempting to use the `aov()` function within a `tapply()` line, and am not sure if it is not possible, or if I'm just coding it incorrectly.

```
Factors<-c("Factor 1", "Factor 2")
Years<-c("Year 1", "Year 2", "Year 3","Year 4", "Year 5")
width<-rnorm(100)
height<-rnorm(100)

mydata<-data.frame(Years,Factors,width,height)
```

I would like to see if there is a difference between the factor levels for each year. Note that my real data has several factor levels, which is why I'm using ANOVA and not a t-test.

I can get the `tapply()` to do 'simple' functions, like `sum`:

```
with(mydata,tapply(width,Factors,FUN="sum"))
```

From the simple examples, I think that the way `tapply()` works is it basically subsets the data by the 2nd entry, `Factors`, then takes the first entry, `width`, and put's it into whatever function is declared. By this reasoning, I tried:

```
with(mydata,tapply(width~Factors,Years,FUN="aov"))
```

This returns an error `arguments must have the same length`.

If it is possible to use `tapply` with function that requires complex input, how do I go about doing this? And I anticipate problems with how to store such output. For example, if I have 2 anova's saved, I would like to save them as a single 'variable name'.

```
width.anova<-with(mydata,aov(width~Factors))
height.anova<-with(mydata,aov(height~Factors))

all.anovas<-c(width.anova, height.anova)
```

What I would like to be able to do is something along the lines of (*following code does not work, just there to show what I'm getting at):

```
#all.anovas$width.anova
```

Clearly the `c()` function does not work. I know that to be able to use the `$` syntax, I should be using a data frame, but the following does not work:

```
all.anovas<-data.frame(width.anova, height.anova)
```

If there is a simpler way of getting the result I'm looking for, any tips on what to do are greatly appreciated. Again, I'm looking to do 5 anovas - comparing the difference between factor levels 1 and 2 for each of 5 years. In reality, my data has 8 years and 5 factor levels. I will be doing these anova's on several variables (like width, and height) as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using the wrong function. You probably want something more like this:

```
lapply(split(mydata,mydata$Years),function(x) aov(width ~ Factors,data = x))
```

or you could use the **plyr** package and do something like this:

```
dlply(mydata,.(Years),function(x) aov(width ~ Factors,data = x))
```

`tapply` is for working with *vectors*, typically, so for more complex objects you'll want a different tool.

To address your comment, perhaps something like this:

```
aov_fun <- function(x,vars){
    out <- vector("list",length(vars))
    names(out) <- vars
    f <- paste0(vars,"~Factors")
    for (i in seq_along(vars)){
        out[[i]] <- aov(as.formula(f[i]),data = x)
    }
    out
}

lapply(split(mydata,mydata$Years),aov_fun,vars = c('width','height'))
```

Comment: `lapply` is exactly what I was looking for. Is there a way to declare all of the variables that I want the anova run on, within 1 line (ie, replace `aov(width~Factors)` with `aov(variables~Factors)` and make a list of the variables somehow, or do I need a separate line for each variable (so one line like you wrote, and another exact copy with `height` replacing `width`)?

Comment: Thanks for the help. The only thing I'm not clear on is the appearance and use of `x` in the code. I thought that `data = ` should be followed by the name of the dataset you want to use, but you have `data=x`, and `x` as an input to the custom function `aov_fun`.

Comment: @user2154249 Scope. You want `aov` to be run on a _subset_ of `mydata`. If you wrote `data = mydata` R would not find any object by that name in the scope of `aov_fun`, and would then proceed to reach back and grab the _full_ data set in the global environment. That is a very common error that would result in running identical aov's on the entire data set.

Comment: @user2154249 So, more to the point, within `aov_fun` the name of the data set we're dealing with is actually `x`.

Comment: It makes sense that if I put `data=mydata` the function would run on the entire dataset, basically making the `split` useless. I guess what confuses me is `x` is not explicitly defined anywhere - it first appears in `function(x)`. 

The code does run perfectly - I just like knowing exactly what's going on. Most of my R problems stem from not understanding exactly what a function needs / will accept as input, or what the function does.

Comment: @user2154249 `x` is defined as the first argument of `aov_fun`, or in the original version as the first (and only) argument to an anonymous function (i.e. a function created only for the `lapply` call which is then discarded). `lapply` hands each list element off to the first argument of whatever function you give it.